# How to address some of many files that include one of a few sequences in their name, in Linux file-name system?

Tags: linux, wildcard, filenames

I have some files in my directory named as:

...
asdfab-18-121.csv
asdfab-19-221.csv
gafaac-19-289.csv
asdfax-19-311.csv
aasdfb-20-122.csv
aasdfb-20-220.csv
aberrc-20-281.csv
aasdfb-21-127.csv
aasdfb-21-224.csv
acadff-21-286.csv
...

I need to list the files that have "-19-" OR "-20-" in the middle part of their name (e.g. lines 2-7 above), at the same time. I know if only one character was variable I could use [seq] syntax. I tried

> ls *@["-19-"|"-20-"]*

but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using `bash` with the `extglob` option turned on, or `ksh93`, or `zsh` with the `KSH_GLOB` option turned on:

```
ls *-@(19|20)-*.csv
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. How can I do a similar thing when copying these files from a remote machine to my local using scp?